# Turn off Twig cache in general

Tags: theming, 8, caching

Drupal does cache Twig templates. Normally, it is a good thing, as long as you don't have a multilingual site.

In my case every `t()`is not working as the template is cached in the wrong in English, giving German no chance to ever be outputted.

Is this the proper way to deal with `t()` calls?

```
 $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null'; 
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

It seems a bit wrong. As I understand these settings are more for the development process, not for production. Also there really should be a setting to use caching in a language specific way.

Comment: Have you thought of including the language in cache tags?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal cache content is language specific. Default is a cache context for the language. Sometimes you need to clear the cache one more time, but then this should work.

You can check this in the database table `cache_render`. All cid's should contain `[languages:language_interface]=langcode` and if you visit the same page in different languages you should see multiple cache entries.

Disabling the cache with a null backend is only for development. For production you need to find a solution for the language specific caching issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen that block do have two types of caches. One for the build array and another one for the block itself (theme, label). How to set the build cache I understand - do you know how to set the other one?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass options to t, specifically the langcode. I believe that would look something like this:

```
{{ 'Your text here'|t({}, {'langcode' => node.language().getId()} }}
```

Untested, so the syntax might be slightly different. Also not sure what woud happen if you pass in a node that has a language like "not specified", it would probably fail.