# t() function - get specific language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

As twig does render templates in the UI language instead of the content language, all the `t()` functions deliver the default language. In my case this is wrong as the ui language is german but the content language can vary.

Can I tell the `t()` function to deliver the translation for Spanish for example?

Comment: Answerd in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223364/turn-off-twig-cache-in-general

Answer (score 2):

You can choose the target language, see more information in the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/8.2.x).

In code it would look like this.

```
$variables['string_in_spanish'] = t(
  'Hello World',
  [], // (The args in the string)
  ['langcode' => 'es'] //  The options
);
```

note that when using the `t()` function, the source language has to be English.